# Get ContentType in ItemAdding Event Handler

Tags: content-type, event-handlers, synchronisation

I need to change a  field in the item being added based on its content type. This needs to happen before the item has been added - hence ItemAdding event receiver. Using ItemAdded is no good since the user will see the original value and would have to refresh the page to see the new value - the same happens when I try to use a workflow to do this.

So is there a way to obtain the ContentType of the item being added in ItemAdding Event Handler?

Thanks

Comment: which SharePoint product are you using ? as you can only use "properties.ListItem.ContentType" in SharePoint 2013 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup you can get content type of item using following code,

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPList list = properties.List; 
    string contentTypeName = properties.AfterProperties["ContentType"].ToString(); 
    SPContentType contentType = list.ContentTypes[contentTypeName]; 
}
```

For more information check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/6f1d67d4-7d46-459a-8b5a-a1d1a64784c3/) out.

Answer (score 1):

**Actual Results from Running Debug**

*SP 2010 - Custom Content Type Event Receiver in a Document Library - override ItemAdding 
...querying the immediate window*

   `? properties.ListItem.ContentType
   'properties.ListItem' is null`


   `? properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"]
   "0x0120D520003BBF99EB54C34597ACF700732E3882F600AA09EB683FFEB74BA408BE00002EB8DE"`


   `? properties.AfterProperties["HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type"]
   "SharePoint.DocumentSet"`

I'm using a Document Library (with the Document Set feature activated) so I have the `HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type` hash-key to give me the English description I'm looking for. On an item list that key probably doesn't exist, so you only have the hash-key `ContentTypeId` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by doing:

> Gets a value that specifies the content type of the list item.
>
> Returns a ContentType.instance representing the content type of the
>   list item.

```
SPContentType = properties.ListItem.ContentType;
```

so for item **adding** it will be:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPContentType ct = properties.ListItem.ContentType;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.contenttype.aspx

Just for clarification for item added event for others:

In the item **added** event its slightly different

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{

    SPList list = properties.listName;  

    string ctName = properties.AfterProperties["ContentType"].ToString();  

    SPContentType contentType = list.ContentTypes[ctName]; 

}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: User clearly said he don't want to use "ItemAdded" however I would like to know why its slightly different in item added event :)

Comment: After reading his question I am pretty sure he knows whats the difference between adding and added and I don't think you needed to add code that I already added using ItemAdding in my answer which was required by User at first place :)

Answer (score 0):

The above code did not work for me, `properties.AfterProperties("ContentType")` was still nothing within `ItemAdding` (SharePoint 2010). However, `properties.AfterProperties("ContentTypeId")` worked. Just wanted to share in case anyone else stumbled upon this with the same issue as me.

```
        Dim currentContentTypeId As New SPContentTypeId(properties.AfterProperties("ContentTypeId").ToString)
        Dim currentContentType As SPContentType = properties.List.ContentTypes(currentContentTypeId)

        If currentContentType.Name = "MyContentType" Then
            'Do stuff
        End If
```

Note that I used `properties.**List**.ContentTypes(...)` and not `properties.**Web**.ContentTypes(...)`. The item being added will have the `ContentTypeId` specific to the current list, which is not the same as the `ContentTypeId` in the site.